# Distribution of oracle jdbc driver and aqapi.jar with application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I put oracle jdbc driver jar and aqapi.jar in local repository. I use gradle to build the distribution of my application.

The questions are:

1) Can i distribute oracle jdbc driver jar and aqapi.jar with my appliation without violating license?

2) Can they be renamed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question regarding software licensing. Consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDBC drivers downloaded from Oracle website are bound by [Oracle Technology Network License Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html). It has entire chapter called *Programs Redistribution* that you probably want to read. There are edge cases that might apply e.g. you are not allowed to redistribute these drivers unless they are shipped with your application.

Comment: Is aqapi.jar bound by Oracle Technology Network License Agreement?

Comment: The aq api is probably even worse. It is typically distributed with your Oracle database, you can't download it. Plus it may be specific to the database version, using a jar file from another database with a different version may be problematic.

Comment: Do note that `ojdbc` driver is also specific to your database version and you shouldn't mix up the version e.g. running 11.0.0.0 on client and 11.0.2.0 on db is asking for trouble.

Comment: You _can_ mix JDBC driver versions and server versions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: @kdowbecki That is very wrong, you can use the older JDBC drivers with newer Oracle versions, and newer JDBC drivers with older Oracle versions. Consult the documentation of a specific Oracle JDBC driver for the supported Oracle versions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel from link further up: [we recommend is, JDBC driver version should always be either same as or higher than the Oracle database version being used](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02). If you dive into OJDBC details there is a lot going on under the hood in each version e.g. see [this link chapter "New Features for Release 2 (11.2)"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548.pdf) . You can decide to be blind and treat the driver a black box but it clearly isn't so it's important to use the right version.

Comment: @kdowbecki You say "is asking for trouble", there won't be trouble, you will just not get some new features.

Comment: Yes, it's "asking for trouble" because the problems can be subtle e.g. difference in network traffic or implicit statement caching. It feels stupid but once you hit an issue like that you start to be cautious and do the right thing, which is keeping driver and database version in sync.